# Correct usage of numbers when talking about rank (e.g., 3, number 3, or third)

Tags: word-choice

Which ones are correct and appropriate for academic and formal writing?

> 1.a) The country's rank dropped from 3 to 5.
>
> 1.b) The country's rank is 3.
>
> 2.a) The country's rank dropped from 3rd to 5th.
>
> 2.b) The country's rank is 3rd .
>
> 3.a) The country's rank dropped from number 3 to number 5.
>
> 3.b) The country's rank is number 3.

Does the answer differ if we substitute the word "rank" with "ranking" in these sentences?

Comment: Adding _number_ in 3 is pointless. It doesn't add anything useful. Between the other two, I think 2 should be prefered.

Comment: Or "The country ranks at number 3", "The country ranks in 3rd place".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of those are grammatically correct.

Among your examples, both group 2 sentences with ordinal numbers are the most natural, however I think we can do even better.

When describing a country's change in rank, in most academic writing contexts, it should already be clear that we're talking about ranks, so you can probably drop the word when describing change:

> The **country dropped** from 3rd to 5th.
> The **country is** 3rd.

If "rank" is required for clarity, then use 2a for changes in rank, and use "rank" as a verb to describe a country's current rank:

> The country **ranks** 3rd.